# Nhibernate cannot find file specified

Tags: nhibernate, t4

I'm creating a t4 template and trying to initialize nhibernate within the template. During t4 runtime, I am getting an error:

Could not load file or assembly 'Network.Framework.Entities' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I understand what the error means but I don't know how to provide this file to the t4 runtime so that it can find it. I've added this file as an assembly and as an import. I've dropped the dll file in VS public assemblies directory, in the t4 temp directory and in the same directory as the template. Nothing works.

and the fusion log:

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\WINNT\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\program files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe

--- A detailed error log follows.

=== Pre-bind state information ===

LOG: User = myself

LOG: DisplayName = Network.Framework.Entities
 (Partial)

WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:

WRN: Assembly Name: Network.Framework.Entities | Domain ID: 77

WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.

WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.

WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,

WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.

WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.

LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/program files/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/

LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL

Calling assembly : NHibernate, Version=3.3.0.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4.

===

LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().

LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\program files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.Config

LOG: Using host configuration file:

LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\WINNT\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.

LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).

LOG: The same bind was seen before, and was failed with hr = 0x80070002.

Here is my template:

```
<#@ template language="C#v4.0" hostspecific="True" debug="True" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#@ assembly name="mscorlib.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Xml.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Configuration.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="EnvDTE.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)SharedDLLs\NHibernate.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)SharedDLLs\nunit.core.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)SharedDLLs\nunit.framework.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)SharedDLLs\NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)SharedDLLs\Iesi.Collections.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)Network.Framework.Entities.Data\bin\Debug\Network.Framework.Entities.Data.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)Network.Framework.Entities\bin\Debug\Network.Framework.Entities.dll" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Diagnostics" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Configuration" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Reflection" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="Network.Framework.Entities.Data.BL" #>
<#@ import namespace="Network.Framework.Entities" #>
<#@ import namespace="NHibernate" #>
<#@ import namespace="NHibernate.Cfg" #>
<#@ import namespace="NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes" #>
<#@ import namespace="EnvDTE" #>
<#@ import namespace="Network.Framework.Entities.DAL" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Xml" #>
<#
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
    string path = Host.ResolvePath(@"..\Network.Framework.Entities\NHibernate.MSSQL.Config.xml");
    T4DataAccess<ReferenceValue> dal = CreateDataAccess<ReferenceValue>(path);
    ReferenceValueBL bl = new ReferenceValueBL(dal);
#>
using System;
namespace Network.Framework.Entities
{
    public class ReferenceValueKey
    {
        <#
            List<ReferenceValue> refVals = bl.Select();
            foreach(ReferenceValue rv in refVals)
            {
                Write("Public ");
                Write(rv.ReferenceValueCode.GetType().Name);
                Write(" ");
                Write(rv.ReferenceValueCode);
                Write(" = ");
                Write(rv.ReferenceValueCode);
            }
        #>
    }
}
<#+ 
    public ISessionFactory GetDBSession(string nHibernateConfigPath)
    {
        NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration cfg = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration().Configure(nHibernateConfigPath);
        var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Network.Framework.Entities.PlanCode));
        var serializedAssembly = HbmSerializer.Default.Serialize(assembly);
        cfg.AddInputStream(serializedAssembly);
        return cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
    }
    public T4DataAccess<T> CreateDataAccess<T>(string nHibernateConfigPath) where T : class
    {
        ISessionFactory db = GetDBSession(nHibernateConfigPath);
        return new T4DataAccess<T>(db);
    }
#>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your app.config

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="NHibernate" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="aa95f207798dfdb4" />
        <bindingRedirect newVersion="3.3.1.4000" oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.3.0.4000" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```